# Are SAQ A-EP network questions office network or a web server network?

Tags: pci-dss

I am not a security expert, and unfortunately we are too small company to have one. Since I am in charge of completing PCI DSS self-assessment questionnaires, I was shocked with the amount of questions specified.

First couple of questions are about firewall, network topology, routers etc, etc. Since we are an e-commerce and we host our web server on a remote location, I would really like to know are those questions regarding our web server or our office location.

Since we do not store or process any credit card information at our office location, we have chosen SAQ A -EP. but I am still not sure which network this questionnaire addresses?

If they are meant for our web server, how can I know all these network settings from a third party hosting. I contacted them (large hosting company) and they explained  they did not have similar request.

Now I am confused did I got this process all wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'scope' that you define is the key to this. You have to justify (according to PCI-DSS rules) that a network (like your office) is not in scope. Then you don't have to worry about that (as long as nothing changes that affects the scope).

As for 3rd party hosting, you need the details from them. They should not be new to PCI-DSS questions. It is possible that they are simply not PCI-DSS compliant, and you will have to review whether they are an appropriate hosting provider for your company.

**You are required to use a PCI-compliant 3rd party as outlined in the "Before You Begin" section of the standard (page iii).**

Comment: But I dont see where can I define this scope in SAQ...

Comment: @mko Self-assessment step 2 : https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/PCI-DSS-v3_2-SAQ-A_EP.pdf?agreement=true You define the scope when you choose to go this route.

Comment: Part 2e also talks about it

Comment: Hm this part 2e was not there when I needed to fill out SAQ via iframe from PCI DSS payment provider.....

Comment: In section Before you Begin states "If merchant website is hosted by a third-party provider, the provider is validated to all applicable
PCI DSS requirements (e.g., including PCI DSS Appendix A if the provider is a shared hosting provider);" My question is the provider is validated by who?

Comment: By PCI itself - that is, they have been audited by them, etc.

Comment: But if I am not mistaking, each web server is a different story. There is no statement like "this web hosting company is PCI DSS compliant". Basically we need to have written assurances by hosting comp. that our web site is PCI DSS complaint and it is up to them to back it up to PCI if or when they got audited. Correct?

Comment: Actually, yes, hosters who are compliant post that fact: http://support.hostgator.com/articles/pre-sales-policies/are-your-servers-pci-compliant

Comment: You need to have that assurance before you can self-qualify for SAQ A-EP. (Before You Begin)

Comment: Do we need to conduct tests stated under expected tests? If so do we need to archive a written copy of these tests?

Comment: @mko yes to both - remember: you need to be able to pass an audit if it ever comes to that